# How i calculate the ball angle after hitting the bat?

Tags: c#, windows, algorithm, game-physics, angle

I am developing an app for cricket gaming. User can bat through gestures. But did not know which algorithm i can use to calculate ball angle after hitting the bat. Like when user play shot on off side, which cricketing area it will select for ball to gone through.

Comment: I think this question belongs to a different forum, check the mathematics of StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a physics engine like,
http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/

so that you don't have to do calculation, and also you don't have to worry about gravity, also you can introduce components like wind to your game with ease if you use something like that.

Comment: I think i have to know how this all works. This physics engine did not advanced my learning. I want to know how the ball direction will be calculated.